# How to make an image as a link independent from a link as a button?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how can I make an image as a link independent from a button as a link. This is a code that I was working with.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    a:link,
    a:visited {
      background-color: #f44336;
      color: white;
      padding: 15px 25px;
      text-align: center;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    
    a:hover,
    a:active {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }
    
    </head>
  </style>

  <body>

    <a href="http://amazon.com" target="_blank">
      <img border="0" src="logo.jpg" width="69" height="36">
    </a>

    <a href="http://youtube.com" target="_blank">This is a link</a>

  </body>

</html>
```

What I got was a red button as a link and an image that had a red frame around it. I would like for the image to be independent from the properties of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I think would be to give your button links independent classes and style those instead.

See example below:

```css
.btn-link:link,
.btn-link:visited {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn-link:hover,
.btn-link:active {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://amazon.com" target="_blank">
  <img border="0" src="https://www.shareicon.net/download/2016/11/14/851937_stack.svg" width="69" height="36">
</a>

<a class="btn-link" href="http://youtube.com" target="_blank">This is a link</a>
```

Above, I have made a `btn-link` class and added that only to the anchor tag which you want to be styled. You can apply this class to all your links which you want to appear as a button.